# Uniformly convergence on Domain and interval(series vs sequence of the function)

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Say $f_n(x)$ (or$ \sum f_n(x)$) : $D \to \mathbb{R}$, Let a bounded interval $I(\subset D)$

First, In the series case

"$\sum f_n(x)$ is a uniformly convergence on $\forall I \Rightarrow$ $\sum f_n(x)$ is a uniformly convergence on $D$"

I've just known that the above is a false statement.

Because I found the counterexample that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} sin({x \over n^2})$.

It is uniformly converge on $\forall I$ like a $[M_1,M_2]$, But it is not uniformly converge on $\mathbb{R}(=D)$ by taking $x=n^2$

Second, Let me focus on the sequence of the functions.

$(*)$ "$f_n(x)$ is a uniformly convergence on $\forall I \Rightarrow$ $f_n$ is a uniformly convergence on $D$"

My guess is it would be still false when we considering $f_n(x)$ instead of the $\sum f_n(x)$. But unlike the series, I can't find any counterexamples. So my question is Is the statement (*) is true? or not, Please help me for finding any counterexamples.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: The sequence $f_n(x) = x^n$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a,b] \subset (0,1)$ but not on $(0,1)$

Comment: @RRL, ah! What a easy counterexample! Thanks. :)